# Prove that if number of edges is greater than ${n-1\choose 2}$, where n is the number of vertices, then G is connected

Tags: graph-theory

My Initial thought is induction on number of edges, but I'm not very good at it

Comment: One method would be to consider how you can get as many edges as possible without it being connected ... this would clearly be when you have two fully connected subgraphs, for if you get even more subgraphs, you 'lose' even more possible edges.. So, now you need to think about how you can split $n$ vertices into two fully connected groups to get as many edges as possible.

Comment: @Bram28 and one way of doing that efficiently is to count the edges in the complement of the graph

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Among all simple graphs on $n$ vertices, the complete graph $K_n$ with $\binom{n}{2}$ edges has the maximum number of edges.

If a graph is not connected, then it has at least two components.

If a graph has two components, say with $n_1$ and $n_2$ vertices, then the maximum number of edges must be $E(n_1, n_2) = \binom{n_1}{2} + \binom{n_2}{2}$.

Show that among all two component graphs with $n_1$ and $n_2$ vertices, that $E(n_1, n_2)$ is maximized when $n_1 = 1$ or $n_2 = 1$.

If a graph has more than $2$ components, the total number of edges is strictly less than any graph where an edge is added between two of these components.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks for the correction--I haven't had lunch today yet!